# three.js; Different texture on each vertex through a shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, webgl, shader

I'm trying to make solar system.. and for the first step, I want to make sun looks glowing.

To do this, `shape = new THREE.BufferGeometry();` and add some attributes. One is `position` and another is `textureOrder`.

I thought that this `textureOrder` can be a index to determine which texture will be used in Fragment Shader, `if(textureOrder == 1.0) use textureA;` something like that;

This `textureOrder` is filled with float values 0.0, 1.0, ..., 5.0 specifically. But I can't use this value as I expected. I guess, its only 0.0 be passed.. ..or not?

Among those textures, one is shown, Not others. I think it's the first one case that `textureOrder = 0.0`.

**- Is it correct way for texturing each vertex with different image? If not, how I can do this?**

Another problem is.. about the `gl_PointSize`. I want my sun being bigger or smaller by distance but since I declared and set `gl_PointSize` value, it's fixed. If I remove `gl_PointSize`, nothings can be seen;

**- How can I stop this fixed-size thing?**

Here is my code..

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vs-sun">
    attribute float textureOrder;
    varying float tOrder;

    void main() {
        tOrder = textureOrder;
        gl_PointSize = 100.0;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fs-sun" >
    uniform float time;
    uniform sampler2D tsun_core;
    uniform sampler2D tsun_innerglow;
    uniform sampler2D tsun_starlight;
    uniform sampler2D tsun_outerglow;
    uniform sampler2D tsun_shortjetlight;
    uniform sampler2D tsun_longjetlight;
    varying float tOrder;

    vec4 getFC() {
        float ratio = 0.01;
        vec3 vColor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

        if(tOrder == 0.0) return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time)) * texture2D(tsun_core, gl_PointCoord);
        else if(tOrder == 1.0) return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time)) * texture2D(tsun_innerglow, gl_PointCoord);
        else if(tOrder == 2.0) return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time)) * texture2D(tsun_starlight, gl_PointCoord);
        else if(tOrder == 3.0) return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time)) * texture2D(tsun_outerglow, gl_PointCoord);
        else if(tOrder == 4.0) return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time)) * texture2D(tsun_shortjetlight, gl_PointCoord);
        else if(tOrder == 5.0) return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time)) * texture2D(tsun_longjetlight, gl_PointCoord);
        else return vec4(vColor, 0.75 + 0.25 * sin(ratio*time));
    }

    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = getFC();
    }
</script>

// Constructing * The Solar *
shape = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    shape.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32Attribute(6,3));
    shape.addAttribute('textureOrder', new THREE.Int8Attribute(6,1));

    for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
        shape.attributes.position.setXYZ(i, 0, 0, 0);
        shape.attributes.textureOrder.setX(i, i);
    };

var d = new Date();

mater = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        time: { type: 'f', value: 1.0 },
        tsun_core: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun_core.png') },
        tsun_innerglow: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun_innerglow.png') },
        tsun_starlight: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun_starlight.png') },
        tsun_outerglow: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun_outerglow.png') },
        tsun_shortjetlight: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun_shortjetlight.png') },
        tsun_longjetlight: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('sun_longjetlight.png') }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vs-sun').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fs-sun').textContent
});
    mater.depthTest = false;
    mater.vertexColor = true;
    mater.transparent = true;
    mater.blending = THREE.AdditiveBlending;

sun = new THREE.ParticleSystem(shape, mater);
scene.add(sun);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way for doing this would be to organize the textures in something called a [texture atlas](https://www.google.com/search?q=texture%20atlas&safe=off&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=LNq-U_nlGeO3sATY4YGICg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=751). Instead of passing that index, pass a vec2, with the offsets already calculated.

For the resizing thing, you can look at the particle shader in three.js. You need to apply perspective shortening to the pointSize.